# How to check whether the sound recording is available in a android device.?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-preferences

Is there a standard way to check whether the sound recording is possible in a android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely need a device to have a microphone, add a `<uses-feature>` element to your manifest asking for `android.hardware.microphone`.

If you could use a microphone if it exists, then add a `<uses-feature>` element to your manifest asking for `android.hardware.microphone` with `android:required="false"`. Then, use `PackageManager` and `hasSystemFeature()` to check for `android.hardware.microphone` at runtime.

Comment: @Shan-mobile: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_MICROPHONE